# PHP - Convert values of array A to an index of array B

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

there's an array A,which has a variable number of values. 
I want to convert  values of array A to an index of array B.

Language: PHP

Example:

```
//array A
$a={'a','b','c','d'};

//converted to an index of array B
$b['a']['b']['c']['d']='somevalue';
```

The problem is that  the number of values of array A is flexible.

Is there a way out?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a=['a','b','c','d'];

$b = [];
$c = &$b;
foreach($a as $key) {
    $c[$key] = $c;
    $c = &$c[$key];
}
$c = 'somevalue';
unset($c);

var_dump($b);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/UM6HI)

Comment: thanks for so quick an answer . I tested this code and got an unexpected result :  array(1) {
  ["a"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["a"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["a"]=>
      *RECURSION*
    }
    ["b"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["a"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["a"]=>
        *RECURSION*
      }
      ["b"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["a"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["a"]=>
          *RECURSION*
        }
        ["b"]=>
        *RECURSION*
      }
      ["c"]=>   ...........

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Mark Baker. I modified some code and it works.

```
$a = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

$b = array();

rsort($a);

$i = 0;
foreach ($a as $v)
{
    if ($i++ > 0)
    {
        $c = array();
        $c[$v] = $b;
        $b = $c;
    }
    else
    {
        $b[$v] = 111;
    }
}

var_dump($b);
```

Result,what I want exactly :

```
array(1) {
  ["a"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["b"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["c"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["d"]=>
        int(111)
      }
    }
  }
}
```